# How do I open Jenkins (port 8080) to the outside?

Tags: jenkins, windows-server-2008

I have jenkins running locally on a Windows Server (2008 R2 Standard). I'm able to access it from http://localhost:8080. However when I try to access this from a remote machine, it fails to load.

Jenkins is running as a windows service.

Is there a way to open port 8080 so I can access Jenkins remotely?

*Note:* I have IIS running and a site setup to point to the Jenkins home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should setup reverse proxy like apache or nginx. You still will be running Jenkins on localhost but reverse proxy will handle requests and ,well, proxy them to Jenkins instance. This way you can have ssl termination to enhance your security for example.